# Raw OpenGL equivillant of GLUPerspective?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

how could I do the same as GluPerspective without Glu? Thanks

ex: gluPerspective(45.0, (float)w / (float)h, 1.0, 200.0);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void gluPerspective( GLdouble fovy, GLdouble aspect, GLdouble zNear, GLdouble zFar )
{
    GLdouble xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

    ymax = zNear * tan( fovy * M_PI / 360.0 );
    ymin = -ymax;
    xmin = ymin * aspect;
    xmax = ymax * aspect;

    glFrustum( xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zNear, zFar );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's explained fairly clearly in the [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) documentation.  You just build up the appropriate 4x4 transformation matrix and use `glMultMatrix` to multiply it into the current transform:

```
void myGluPerspective(double fovy, double aspect, double zNear, double zFar)
{
    double f = 1.0 / tan(fovy * M_PI / 360);  // convert degrees to radians and divide by 2
    double xform[16] =
    {
        f / aspect, 0, 0, 0,
        0,          f, 0, 0,
        0,          0, (zFar + zNear)/(zNear - zFar), -1,
        0,          0, 2*zFar*zNear/(zNear - zFar), 0
    };
    glMultMatrixd(xform);
}
```

Note that OpenGL stores matrices in *column-major* order, so the order of array elements above is transposed from what's written in the `gluPerspective` documentation.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, converting degrees to radians is degToRad(deg) { return deg * M_PI/ 180.0; }, so the first line should be 180 instead of 360.

Comment: @prewett: It's not just converting from degrees to radians, it's also dividing by 2.  The `gluPerspective` docs spell out the equation `f = cotangent(fovy / 2)`; when you throw in the degrees-to-radians conversion, the `fovy / 2` becomes `fovy * M_PI / 360`.

Comment: Oops, I see that in your comment now.  My window on my Mac is too small to see the full comment and the stupid Lion+ scrollbars don't show up until you actually scroll, so I didn't see that there was more past the radians part.  Sorry about that.