# Projection Matrix yielding incorrect results

Tags: c++, opengl, math, perspectivecamera, glm-math

I am currently trying to create a Perspective function, that yields a Projection for OpenGL. I have created it many, many ways, the latest replicating GLM's function that handles it (I have to use my own Matrix4 class for my assignment). No matter what code I try, I always yield incorrect numbers compared to GLM, which leads to my cube only rendering with GLM.

They are both initialised with the same variables

```
glm::mat4 ProjectionGLM = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
Matrix4 Projection = Matrix4::Perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Perspective function

```
Matrix4 Matrix4::Perspective(double fov, double aspect, double zNear, double zFar) {
double fovy = fov * 0.0174532925;

double const tanHalfFovy = tan(fovy / 2.0f);

Matrix4 temp;
temp.data[0][0] = 1.0f / (aspect * tanHalfFovy);
temp.data[1][1] = 1.0f / (tanHalfFovy);
temp.data[2][2] = -(zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
temp.data[2][3] = -1.0f;
temp.data[3][2] = -(2.0f * zFar * zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
return temp;
```

The code is directly modelled after GLM's, minus the static_cast's and the templating. It's the same math as many other function's I have tried. Yet the resulting matrix is different.

GLM result

```
1.34444320 0          0            0
0          1.79259098 0            0
0          0          -1.00200200  -1.00000000
0          0          -0.200200200 0
```

My results

```
1.81066012 0          0            0
0          2.41421366 0            0
0          0          -1.00200200  -1.00000000
0          0          -0.200200200 0
```

Any idea on what could be wrong with my perspective function or what GLM could be doing differently?

Link to my math library (just .h and .cpp files)
https://mega.co.nz/#!lokhCBaB!5r7GwpWhEZ-tUcXV_ccxmQvZgRwIVU8K7dlIffVqZic

Comment: GLM is using radians, your code degrees...

Comment: This may be relevant:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058552/raw-opengl-equivillant-of-gluperspective

Comment: I convert the FoV to radians on the first line of the function.

Comment: I looked at that function, edited it so:
    double f = 1.0 / tan(fov * PI / 360);
    temp.data[0][0] = f / aspect;
    temp.data[1][1] = f;

Exact same resulting Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLM takes the FOV angle in radians, while the value you pass (`45.0`) is in degrees.

The [GLM documentation](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00171.html#gac3613dcb6c6916465ad5b7ad5a786175) for the parameter is about as unclear as it could be:

> Specifies the field of view angle, in degrees, in the y direction. Expressed in radians.

Yes, that both says that it's in degrees and in radians. But if you look at the source code, it's indeed radians.

This is consistent with your result. For matrix element `[2][2]`, which is:

```
1.0 / tan(0.5 * fov)
```

Evaluated with the `tan()` function operating in radians, this produces the following when using `45.0` directly:

```
1.0 / tan(0.5 * 45.0) = 1.0 / tan(22.5) = 1.79251
```

When converting the angle to radians first:

```
1.0f / tan(0.5 * 45.0 * pi / 180.0) = 1.0 / tan(0.3927) = 2.41421
```

So if you convert the input angle for the GLM versions to radians, my prediction is that you will get the same value as the one you calculated yourself:

```
glm::mat4 ProjectionGLM = glm::perspective(45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for this, I was so confused on GLM's input. I changed my code and got the same result as GLM.